# Fetching Facebook friends with Graph API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

I am trying to retrieve the list of facebook friends of a logged user in an Iphone app.

this is the code I am using

```
[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
```

the result I get is a NSDictionary instance with only an object inside.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: did you send the auth code and the access token ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You parse your DIctionary Data.

Sample code here,

```
  if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {

            NSArray *userInfoArray=[result objectForKey:@"data"];


            NSMutableArray *userIdArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc ]init];
            NSMutableArray *userNameArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc ]init];

            for (int indexVal=0; indexVal<[userInfoArray count]; indexVal++) {
                NSDictionary *individualUserInfo=[userInfoArray objectAtIndex:indexVal];

                [userIdArray addObject:[individualUserInfo objectForKey:@"id"]];
                [userNameArray addObject:[individualUserInfo objectForKey:@"name"]];
            }

            NSLog(@"Frnd Name Array : %@ ",userNameArray);
            NSLog(@"Id Array : %@ ",userIdArray);
}
```

Here **result** is the data you received in request:DidLoad delegate method